# pkcs12 keystore password was incorrect in java

Tags: java, eclipse, certificate, pkcs#12

I'm having this error in Eclipse when I try to load pkcs12 certificate from my classpath:

[image]

In my siaval.properties I have a refference to the URL of my .p12 file:

```
client.authentication.method=Signature
sign.keystore.type=PKCS12
sign.keystore.url=firma/acceso_ws_tspcrypto.p12
sign.keystore.password={myEncryptedPassword}
client.domain=mydomain
```

I'm having this "keystore password" error only if I try to use the p12 file in the classpath of my Java app, but if I change the `sign.keystore.url=firma/acceso_ws_tspcrypto.p12` for the same file but located at my desktop `C:/Users/mysuer/Desktop/firma/cert/acceso_ws_tspcrypto.p12` everything works fine.

Why am I having this error?

Comment: perhaps /cert/ folder is the cause?